# Reduce number of weak classifiers in lower stages. OpenCV cascade classifier

Tags: opencv

My cascade classifier takes about 1-2 seconds to process one frame with 4gb RAM Intel Core i5 2.6 GHz.

I have built my cascade with OpenCV using this command:

```
opencv_traincascade -data data -vec positives.vec -bg bg.txt -numPos 1300 -numNeg 3000 -numStages 20 -w 30 -h 30 -featureType HAAR
```

Now it has 45, 51, 57, 69, 72 weak classifiers in first five stages, where Viola-Jones detection has 1, 10, 25, 25 and 50 and it says that on average 10 features out of 6000+ are evaluated per sub-window. I think that there is the reason why my classifier is that slow.

How could I reduce the number of weak classifiers in the first stages and put there the ones which are the best of weak's, to make object detection faster?

Comment: You could try specifying `-precalcBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024` to increase the amount of RAM it uses. The parameters are in MB, and the default parameters for both are 512.

Comment: @EdwardShen you got me wrong. I'm ok with training process. The problem is that my object detection takes too much time and I think thats because of too much weak classifiers in first stages of a cascade. However, thanks for advice.

Comment: My apologies. Try playing around with the booster classifier parameters specified in [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html#cascade-training), especially `-bt` and `-maxWeakCount`. I'm not sure that if that will help, but it's something. Otherwise, it doesn't seem like there's a specific parameter to limit the weak classifiers. Recognition might also be slow because your negatives may have images that are very similar to your positives, and thus each stage requires a more complex set of weak classifiers.

Comment: @EdwardShen - Thanks for suggestion! I think that the similarity between my positives and negatives might be the case.

Comment: @LiudasIndrašius how did you solve this problem ?